# SSH Key - How can I add a new key to github?

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm attempting to add pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub in GitHub but this is the error message I'm getting: Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format.

Any suggestions on how I can add this? I've googles several different commands.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

libsecp256k1-static/stable 20200902-1 arm
Static libraries for libsecp256k1

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the file destination (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) and copy past it into GitHub. Follow steps 1, 2 & 3 to get to where you want to paste it. After Copy pasting use command (in Git Bash) `ssh -t git@github.com` to authenticate.

[image: Follow the steps 1, 2 & 3 to get to where you want to past the SSH Key]

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users, there are two things to consider

1. your console should parse quotation and double quotation in the right order.
2. curl needs quotation for JSON properties and keys.

So how can we debug it:

- Add "-v --trace-ascii -" to the curl command to see log for command.
- Use  echo or write-host for your data in cmd or PowerShell

It is so important to make sure that curl receives valid JSON data.

See an example for Windows PowerShell [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71158464/5925125)